# Can I add an Angular theme template to an existing project?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I ALREADY have an Angular15 project going. I don't want to lose time building a UI from scratch.

I want to use a template like this Angular14:

[image]

https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-angular2#

Is there a way I can merge these 2 Angular projects together?

How do I go about merging the two? I have the template in an entirely separate angular project folder. I manually copy/paste pages and SCSS? What's the plan?

[image]

Thank you for your time

Comment: yes why not. what's bothering you?

Comment: high speed particle accelerator should handle it....

Comment: How do I go about merging the two? I have the template in an entirely separate angular project folder. I manually copy/paste pages and SCSS? What's the plan?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your problem is to create the Angular project that you are trying to merge into an Angular library,
see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Lmjjnfljc4.

Then, wrap the components/pages that you want to reuse in your application, and call them into your template.